# How to write a event listener to update global variable in react native navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

My navigation system is bottomTabNavigator

In `Dashboard` screen I have bluetooth connection listner that update global variable like so

```
      BluetoothManager.connect(row.address).then(
        success => {
          Alert.alert('Alert', 'Success')
          global.appState = `Successfully connected to ${row.name}`
        }
```

When the connection is lost I run this

```
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
      BluetoothManager.EVENT_CONNECTION_LOST,
      () => {
        console.log('EVENT_CONNECTION_LOST')
        global.appState = 'No device connected'
      },
    )
```

In that screen everything works fine but on the other screen no way to update that variable by simply doing setState so I have used an infinite loop but I know it's bad for performance, how can I only update that component when variable changes?

```
// Tickets.js

UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate() {
    this.appState = setTimeout(() => { 
        this.setState(() => ({appState: global.appState}))
        console.log('global.appState :', global.appState);
      }, 1000);
}

UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    clearTimeout(this.appState);
}
```

Comment: *on the other screen no way to update that variable* - why?

Comment: I mean by simply doing setState, it has to be constantly updated

Comment: The answer to your problem is to not use global variables to manage state in react

Comment: Sounds like a job for [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)